# Bootstrap 5 horizontal and vertical center on form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align my bootstrap form horizontally and vertically so that it is in the middle of the screen; however, I can't find any solution to help me.

I tried using these bootstrap classes, but they did not work:
`d-flex` `align-items-center` `justify-content-center`

Here's my form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <form>
      <div class="mb-3 form-control-sm">
        <label for="loginInputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 form-control-sm">
        <label for="loginInputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginInputPassword">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 form-control-sm">
        <label for="selectAccountType" class="form-label">Account type</label>
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="selectAccountType" aria-label="selectAccountType">
          <option selected>Account type</option>
          <option value="1">Arbetare</option>
          <option value="2">Företag</option>
          <option value="3">Admin</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 form-check form-control-sm">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="rememberCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberCheck">Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you upload your code and also try using padding!

Comment: added code now and I would like to do it with bootstrap classes preferably.

Comment: Why use padding @Aahad?

Comment: What is your issue? in the snippet your code works fine

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it simply aligns it in the center horizontally but not vertically, its not in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It's doing exactly what is supposed to do. Your parent class: `<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">` doesn't have an height set. This means that your form will take all of its available space.

If you want to achieve to center it horizontal and vertical, you can set the height of your parent class to: `100vh`.

I updated your code: https://codepen.io/Qontrol/pen/xxRqgJG

Comment: Link dead, downvote.  That's why external code is bad

Answer (score 15):

Looks like parent `div` needs a vertical height, could use 100% of viewport height with `vh-100`:

```html
  <body>
    <!-- vh-100 here-->
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center vh-100">
      <form>
        <div class="mb-3 form-control-sm">
          <label for="loginInputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-control-sm">
          <label for="loginInputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginInputPassword">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-control-sm">
          <label for="selectAccountType" class="form-label">Account type</label>
          <select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="selectAccountType" aria-label="selectAccountType">
            <option selected>Account type</option>
            <option value="1">Arbetare</option>
            <option value="2">Företag</option>
            <option value="3">Admin</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check form-control-sm">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="rememberCheck">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberCheck">Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You saved my 2 days of work, Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation.